# How to override docker-compose values in multiple combined files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

Letzt imagine i have 3 compose files (only focus on the mysql service)

> docker-compose.yml
>
> docker-compose.staging.yml
>
> docker-compose.prod.yml

In my docker compose.yml i have my basic mysql stuff with dev als build target

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  mysql:
    build:
      target: dev
    ...
```

And start it with

> docker-compose up -d

In my staging environment i would like to expose port 3306, but also want another build target so i would create the docker-compose.staging.yml with the following content.

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  mysql:
    build
      target: prod
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

And combine it with

> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.staging.yml up -d

So the build target is overwritten and the port 3306 is now exposed to the outside.

Now i want the same in the docker-compose.prod.yml, just without having the port 3306 exposed to the outside ... How can i override the ports directive to not having ports exposed?

I tried to put an empty array in the prod.yml without success (port is still exposed):

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  mysql:
    ports: []
```

In the end i would like to stack the up command like this:

> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.staging.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d

I also know the docs says

> For the multi-value options ports, expose, external_links, dns, dns_search, and tmpfs, Compose concatenates both sets of values

But how can i reach my goal anyway without duplicating configuration?

Yes for sure, i could omit the docker-compose.staging.yml but in the staging.yml are build steps defined, which should also be used for the prod stage to not have any differences between the built container.
So duplicating things isn't really an option.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might consider using `extends` key in your compose files like this:

```
mysql:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose.yml
    service: mysql
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  # other definitions
```

Although you'd have to change your compose version from `3.4` to < `3` ( like `2.3` ) because v3 doesn't support this feature [ref](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31101) as there is a open feature request hanging for a long time now.

**Important note** here is that you shouldn't expose any ports in your base `docker-compose.yml` file, only on the specific composes.

[Oficial docs ref for extends](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#extends)

**edit**

`target` clause is not supported in `v2.0` so I've adjusted the answer to match the `extends` and `target` requirement. That's compose `v2.3`.

**edit from comments**

As there is a `deploy` keyword requirement, then there is `compose v3` requirement. And as for now, there is no possibility to extend composes. I've read in some official doc (can't find it now for ref) that **they encourage us to use flat composes specific for environment** so that it's always clear. Also Docker states that's hard to implement in v3 (ref in the above issue) and it's not going to be implemented anywhere soon. You have to use separate compose files per environment.

Comment: I used docker-compose  < 3 before but it seems that here the "target" directive isn't supported :/

Comment: Oh, i misunderstood ... they wrote for the target directive "added in 3.4" so i thought just 3.4 und upward ... but also in version 2.x doc they said  "added in 2.3" ... so i will give it a try

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't check that before posting, I've just spotted it too, try with `2.3`. Will adjust my answer.

Comment: Ok, i've seen now, we are also using the "deploy" directive, so < v3 isn't suitable for my needs :/ Thanks anyway

Comment: Ahh, that's a important thing to know ;)

Comment: Added note considering your addition. Please accept the answer if it helped you clear the situation out.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually strongly suggest just not using the "target" command in your compose files. I find it to be extremely beneficial to build a single image for local/staging/production - build once, test it, and deploy it in each environment. In this case, you change things using environment variables or mounted secrets/config files.

Further, using compose to build the images is... fragile. I would recommend building the images in a CI system, pushing them to a registry, and then using the image version tags in your compose file- it is a much more reproducible system.

Comment: I used the "target" command because i don't want to have multiple Dockerfiles ... for example i want to have installed xdebug on my dev image but not using it in production ... therefore i built a "base image" and a "dev image" which is based on the base image ... its nearly the same with except for the installed xdebug ... how can i reach it without writing multiple dockerfiles? I thought the target was excactly made for thos cases ...

Comment: Ah I actually misread- I had thought I saw "target: staging" in there as well. In that case, just build the images outside the compose file and you don't need the staging.yml for your prod deploy.